# Django - Restricting views

Tags: django

I am building a website where you can keep your private portfolio, logs, etc using Django.

All courses, documentation, I came accross so far give all users the possibility to view all entries made by all users (e.g. blog, posts etc.). However I want to restrict any user from viewing & READING other users' data.

How can this be best achieved? Is there an extension available? I know that django doesn't have row-level permissions, but there are extensions for that available such as Django-rules. 
In my case however I want restrict a user from viewing other users' data. In other words, a user can only see his/her porfolio and is also not in any way able to CHANGE, UPDATE, DELETE any entries which is not its own.

Comment: You could write a middleware which restricts all the incoming requests

Comment: You can use a [class decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I found that django-guardian does the job.